# Select between dates on DD.MM.YYYY format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

How can I select all rows between two dates, where the dateformat is `DD.MM.YYYY`?

For example between `15.12.2013` and `25.12.2013`

Comment: Fix your data to store dates as dates, not as strings.

Comment: Dates don't have a format. Are you storing them as a `varchar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gordon and the Horse have commented, you should seriously consider storing your dates as a date type and not as text.  That being said, you can convert your date column to a `datetime` using SQL Server's `CONVERT()` function and then compare that against the date range.

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE CONVERT(datetime, date_col, 104) BETWEEN '2013-12-15' AND '2013-12-25'
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of converting to `datetime`, using `between`, and using  `YYYY-MM-DD`;
I would recommend converting to `date`, using `>= and <=`, and `YYYYMMDD`:

```
select *
from t
where convert(date, date_col, 104) >= '20131215' 
  and convert(date, date_col, 104) <= '20131225'
```

- [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

> As an example, even if you try to use the seemingly unambiguous YYYY-MM-DD, this can break under certain scenarios -- such as when the user's language settings are set to French:

- [What do `between` and the devil have in common? - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)